# Integrate Angular 5 with ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to integrate an Angular 5 app generated with CLI project into an existing ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I created the angular project with CLI inside the ASP.NET MVC project, and I want to use Angular 5 components inside razor views; those will be simple razor views and inside those, I will display some Angular 5 components. I've done this with ASP.NET Core 2, I changed the  `Outdir` property to `wwwroot` in the file `.angular-cli.json`, and it worked, but I could not do it with ASP.NET MVC 5. Can anyone help? Thank you

PS: many tutorials use old versions of Angular and they used a file named `system.js`, but this file does not exist anymore in the newer versions of Angular.

Comment: Any success for the same???? please update.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbHSTJBhJ44

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen the release candidate for the new Microsoft Core Angular template.  They changed the template so that it uses angular-cli.  Works well.  You could possibly follow the same build config pattern. Note you have to install the newest version of the template via

dotnet new --install Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates::2.0.0-rc1-final.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?tabs=visual-studio#tabpanel_IjUmMTId-R_visual-studio

Answer (score 20):

I just did this with Angular 5 and MVC 5. I suggest you get a "Hello World" working first, and then port it into your existing MVC problem.

Pre-reqs - make sure you have the latest Node, NPM, AngularCLI installed...

1. In VS2017, create a New ASP.NET Web Application, SPA with MVC and WebAPI 1.1. Show all files (in the Solution Explorer - this makes things easier!)
2. From the package manager console uninstall unneeded packages:

   ```
   UnInstall-Package Sammy.js
   UnInstall-Package Bootstrap
   UnInstall-Package JQuery
   UnInstall-Package Knockout.validation
   UnInstall-Package Knockoutjs
   UnInstall-Package modernizr
   UnInstall-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web -RemoveDependencies
   ```
3. Remove all bundles in `BundleConfig.cs` (we'll pull them in later!)
4. Delete Scripts folder (it will be recreated using the AngularCLI)
5. Add Angular using CLI (go into the project root folder)

   Run: `ng new Scripts --skip-tests --style scss`

   In the Project, Include all folders EXCEPT `node_modules`!
6. Update `angular.json` to output to a `Bundles` folder -> `"outputPath": "../Bundles"`
7. Add bundles:

   ```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Script/Bundles") 
          .Include("~/bundles/inline.*", "~/bundles/polyfills.*", 
                   "~/bundles/scripts.*", "~/bundles/vendor.*", "~/bundles/runtime.*", 
                   "~/bundles/main.*"));

   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Styles") .Include("~/bundles/styles.*"));
   ```
8. (Optional) Re-add libraries through NPM (command prompt from Scripts folder):

   ```
   npm install jquery --save   
   npm install popper.js --save    
   npm install bootstrap --save
   ```
9. (Optional) Reference them in angular.json so AngularCLI pulls them into the webpack bundles:

   ```
   "styles": [
         "src/styles.scss",
         "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
       ],
   "scripts": [
         "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
         "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
         "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
       ]
   ```
10. Build from scripts folder: `ng build --extractCss`
11. In `_Layout.cshtml`, add:

    ```
      @Styles.Render("~/Content/Styles")    <!-- In the "head" element -->
    ```

    and

    ```
      @Scripts.Render("~/Script/Bundles")   <!-- At the end of the "body" element -->
    ```

    Remove the old bundle imports!
12. In `Home/Index.cshtml`, add the Angular element:

    ```
    <app-root>test</app-root>
    ```

    13.1 Remove the old bundle imports!
13. Run the web app - it should open up. Register a new user, and then login. Show the MVC5 demo page together with the Angular
14. To "watch" the webpage - from the command line:

    ```
    ng build --extractCss --watch
    ```

This will rebuild the Bundles. Unfortunately you need to refresh the browser, but this is better than stop/starting things!

Shout if you need more detail - I've run through this twice to get familiar with it, and it works nicely!

Comment: Hi James, U solution worked fantastically , but I was facing issues in deploying to Azure app service, can u please help me on how to deploy the above solution to azure

Comment: Hi Mawy, thats a big topic. I don't use Azure, but on AWS I prefer an "old school" deployment method. I run an MSBuild script to "ng build --prod" which creates prod bundles of Angular etc, then an MSBuild to build the MVC5 website project. Then I copy this to a shared folder on the destination server. The destination server is running IIS7, and the share is within inetpub/wwwroot. In IIS I generally create a new virtual directory, and my shared folder sits right there... I hope that helps steer you? Otherwise raise the question and I'll try give a bigger answer...

Comment: @JamesJoyce, Following the steps mentioned, I am getting the error   _Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements_

Comment: @Kng-web - you haven't put in the html element <app-root></app-root> into your MVC view. This is where Angular will inject it's output HTML, which you define as an element selector in your app.component.ts... Put one into the MVC view where you render the Angular scripts...

Comment: Thanks, @JamesJoyce. Great answer. Just used it with great success. One minor correction: Step 5: `ng new Scripts --skip-tests --style=scss`

Comment: Wow I used this to integrate a .net 4.8 mvc that use to have AngularJS with Angular 17. It works! I only have some issues with using json files that were used for configuration in the angular app. I have to find a workaround for that, but this is a great step!

Answer (score 0):

Solution and how to do it using Angular 4.3 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2tpXcor6wU):

Comment: For posterity, could you include the relevant parts of the link which you found useful in your answer? That way, if the link goes down, changes, etc., your answer won't be rendered useless. Many thanks.

Comment: Just for convenience: those who know about MVC can skip all that explanation and go directly to "How to include Angular" https://youtu.be/-2tpXcor6wU?t=4703

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling to find working/simple instructions in 2021 here are the steps I finally got working to add an Angular 10.x app to an ASP.NET (CORE) 3.x MVC web application:
https://gist.github.com/cemerson/1af0befa4edc959a02ba1a34784c6d55