# Can't access Angular Components via URL

Tags: html, angular, routes

I've made an Angular Application which should sit on top of an .NET-Application. There is an Index-View of the ASP.Net-Application from which I should call a certain Angular-View.

For testing I tried locally host the application with `http serve` - here I can only access the index.html(which in my case has no entries) - a route like `/users`to go to the User-Overview leads to an 404.

Here is my Routing-Module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'users', component: UsersComponent},
  {path: 'user/new', component: UserNewComponent},
  {path: 'user/edit/:id', component: UserEditComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I know that it should be an Single-Page-Application - but right now, for that iteration it should be like that. How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you build your Angular Application to generate index.html @FlixRo

Comment: If I look into the `/dist` folder it is there - so I guess yes

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823670/integrate-angular-5-with-asp-net-mvc-5/48210691

Comment: Is it really necessary to wire the angular-application into the asp.net application? I had something like a seperated front- and backend in mind in which I access the frontend over the routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add an web.config with explicit re-writing rules for IIS aswell as URL-Rewriter 2.

Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
```

Try `useHash: true` in `app.routing` file. 
This works for me.

Comment: Still getting a `404` for any other route than index.html

Comment: Are you able to access the component with routerlink? If yes then this may be the issue on localhost only this will work on the server after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a server that redirects all the routes to `index.html`. `http serve` wont do that.

Internally, Angular handles the routes by use of something called virtual routes.

For Example:

In Node.js we have something like,

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(frontend_path, 'index.html'));
});
```

For development purposes, you could run a local server using,

`ng serve`

In top-level Angular Directory

Comment: Is there a way how I can test it in a simple way?

Comment: Use `ng serve` in angular folder where `package.json` exists @FlixRo

Comment: But this is the normal way of doing it development, right? Because while starting it via ng serve and running on webpack-dev-server it works like a charm - the app listens on default at localhost:4200. Therefore it works without a problem. But if I build it, it doesnt work.

Comment: Exactly, For Production, you'll need an server to redirect all incoming routes to `index.html` or use a reverse proxy to route those requests.

Comment: But how can I achieve my expected behaviour if the Asp.NET-Application calls /users to link to that View but then gets re-routed to index? Or do I miss something?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASP .Net, But I do use Nodejs to achieve the same. Every view is loaded by angular inside of index.html. Youll need to have [*{url}] to redirect to index.html